# HTML parsing bug(ish) in expanded usercards

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-card

I'm Chris on stackoverflow.  Recently got my established user priv, so I finally filled out my 'about me' section of my profile. I just put some old usenet computer-related haikus there for fun.

The bug I noticed is this.. I format the two haikus like this:

```
blah blah blah blah blah<br/>
blah blah blah blah blah, blah blah<br/>
blah blah blah blah blah<br/>

foo foo foo foo foo<br/>
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.<br/>
foo foo foo foo foo<br/>
```

It looks ok in the editor preview and the "about me" greyish box on my profile, but in the usercard it winds up looking like this (tested with IE 8 and Firefox 8):

```
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah, blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
foo foo foo foo foo
```

I'm cool with the lack of a linebreak between the two, but the second paragraph isn't getting shown right.  Hate to be that kind of a stickler, but can that be fixed?

Comment: I _think_ they're only limited to 5 or 6 lines but yours tries to span 7 (including the blank line) so the last line gets kinda truncated (and the blank line just doesn't get rendered).  I think that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff Mercado is correct; there is a limit of three manual line breaks. Everything from the fourth is just replaced with a space.